# Ant design in MERN boilerplate

Tags: antd

Want to use [ant design](http://ant.design) in a project together with the [MERN boilerplate](http://mern.io) but having problems with the integration.

I've installed the antd and babel-plugin-import and added this to my .babelrc

```
"import",
  {
    "libraryName": "antd",
    "style": "css"
  }
```

Since I use webpack, do I have to change something there?

When I start the server, I get: **Can't resolve 'antd/lib/sider/style/css'**

I have looked around on many boilerplates and tried to integrate that into my project, but can't get it to work.

Here is my [github repo](https://github.com/Danielbook/liftinglog)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you just use webpack 2.x, the config may be different.

- https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/wiki/FAQ#how-to-use-antd-with-webpack2
- https://github.com/ant-design/babel-plugin-import/search?q=webpack2&type=Issues&utf8=%E2%9C%93

Comment: Thanks! Will look into that :)